# Complex Property Kendo Datasource

Tags: c#, entity-framework, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, complextype

Consider the following

**MODEL**

```
public partial class ElementType
{
    public long ElementTypeId { get; set; }
    public LocalizedString TypeName { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class LocalizedString
{
    public string French { get; set; }
    public string English { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string Current
    {
        get { return (string) LanguageProperty().GetValue(this,null); }
        set { LanguageProperty().SetValue(this, value,null); }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Current;
    }

    private PropertyInfo LanguageProperty()
    {
        string currentLanguage = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.DisplayName;
        return GetType().GetProperty(currentLanguage);
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult ElementType_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    List<ElementType> elementTypeList = db.ElementType.ToList();
    IQueryable<ElementType> elementTypes = elementTypeList.AsQueryable();


    DataSourceResult result = elementTypes.ToDataSourceResult(request, elementType => new
    {
        ElementTypeId = elementType.ElementTypeId,
        TypeName = elementType.TypeName,
    });

    return Json(result);
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult ElementType_Destroy([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, ElementType elementType)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var currentElementType = db.ElementType.Find(elementType.ElementTypeId);
        db.ElementType.Attach(currentElementType);
        db.ElementType.Remove(currentElementType);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return Json(new[] { elementType }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

Read action is working as expected. I'm getting the current TypeName in the Grid view by TypeName.Current

But if I try to execute any other actions, like Destroy or Update I'm getting this exception ***Can not convert an object of type 'Iolite.Models.LocalizedString' to type 'System.String'.***

Any suggestion to fix it?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use DTOs (Data Transfer Object) to flat your model into easier to serialize/deserialize objects. You will also reduce the amount of data that will be transferred between your server & clients within every request.

For your particular implementation you might define a DTO as follow:

```
public class ElementTypeDTO
{
    public long ElementTypeId { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
}
```

According to this architectural pattern you have to change your actions as follow:

```
public ActionResult ElementType_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    List<ElementType> elementTypeList = db.ElementType.ToList();
    IQueryable<ElementType> elementTypes = elementTypeList.AsQueryable();


    DataSourceResult result = elementTypes.ToDataSourceResult(request, elementType => new ElementTypeDTO
    {
        ElementTypeId = elementType.ElementTypeId,
        TypeName = elementType.TypeName.Current,
    });

    return Json(result);
}

[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult ElementType_Destroy([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, ElementTypeDTO elementType)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var currentElementType = db.ElementType.Find(elementType.ElementTypeId);
        db.ElementType.Attach(currentElementType);
        db.ElementType.Remove(currentElementType);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    return Json(new[] { elementType }.ToDataSourceResult(request, ModelState));
}
```

Comment: I see no reasons to use a DTO in this scenario, specially because I might need the object. Moreover, if the property `TypeName` was set as `string` I would not get `TypeName.Current` from my DTO as shown on your code.